# T-SQL - Return list of values to IN clause depending on another list of values

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, clause

The gist is, I want to return a list of `employee_id` numbers for the `IN` clause.

I am given a list of `employee_id`s like `(2,3,4,5)` and a `company_id` like `5`. Some of these belong to `company=5`, some do not. If any of these belong to `company=5`, then I want to ONLY use those id numbers in the `IN` clause. If NONE of the given `employee_id` numbers belongs to `company=5`, then I want to return ALL `employee_id` numbers for `company=5`.

I have the logic here, but unfortunately you can't return multiple values inside a `WHEN` clause from a sub select so this statement returns an error.

I am trying to modify an existing `WHERE` clause so I need the changes to be in place in this statement and without the use of cursors or the like. I know there must be a way to convert these to a series of AND/OR, but I cannot figure it out.

Thank you for any help!

```
SELECT employee_id FROM employees
WHERE company_id=5
  AND employee_id IN (
    CASE
          WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT employee_id FROM employees WHERE company_id=5 AND employee_id IN (2,3,4,5)) THEN
              SELECT employee_id FROM employees WHERE company_id=5       
          ELSE
              SELECT employee_id FROM employees WHERE company_id=5 AND employee_id IN (2,3,4,5)
    END
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
SELECT employee_id FROM employees 
WHERE company_id=5
and employee_id IN (2,3,4,5)
and exists (select * from employees where company_id = 5 and employee_id IN (2,3,4,5))
union all
SELECT employee_id FROM employees 
WHERE company_id=5
and Not exists (select * from employees where company_id = 5 and employee_id IN (2,3,4,5))
```

Only one of the exists/not exists can fire.  So this will do one select or the other, but without the use of If or Case statements.  The first exists is probably unnecessary... so

```
SELECT employee_id FROM employees 
WHERE company_id=5
and employee_id IN (2,3,4,5)
union all
SELECT employee_id FROM employees 
WHERE company_id=5
and Not exists (select * from employees where company_id = 5 and employee_id IN (2,3,4,5))
```